# U-boot bare-metal crash on eret

Tags: pi-3, bare-metal, u-boot

I've been playing around with bare metal programming on a Raspberry Pi 3B, and I recently started using u-boot, rather than moving the SD card back and forth. However, the following startup code, which works perfectly fine without a bootloader, is not working when I load it with u-boot.

```
.section ".text.boot"
  
.globl _start
_start:
    mov x0, 0x30d00000
    orr x0, x0, 0x0800
    msr SCTLR_EL1, x0

    mov x0, 0x80000000
    msr HCR_EL2, x0

    mov x0, 0x01c5
    msr SPSR_EL2, x0

    adr x0, el1_entry
    msr ELR_EL2, x0
    eret

el1_entry:
    mov sp, 0x08000000
    bl kernel
```

In the kernel function, I print a message to the mini UART telling me the current exception level. Without u-boot, it drops down to EL1 as expected. With u-boot, if I comment out the `eret`, then it does make it into the kernel function and prints the message confirming that it's at EL2.

```
## Starting application at 0x000800
Hello World!
Current Exception Level: 0x02
```

However, when I un-comment the `eret`, then it gives me this output:

```
## Starting application at 0x00080000 ...


U-Boot 2018.11-dirty (Jun 21 2022 - 10:43:48 -0600)

DRAM:  948 MiB
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0 
Waiting for Ethernet connection... done.
Using smsc95xx_eth device
TFTP from server 192.168.x.x; our IP address is 192.168.x.x
Filename 'rpi-3b/chuck/kernel8.img'.
Load address: 0x80000
Loading: ##################################################  1.3 KiB
         8.8 KiB/s
done
Bytes transferred = 1347 (543 hex)
## Starting application at 0x00080000 ...
"Synchronous Abort" handler, esr 0x02000000
elr: ffffffffc4daf010 lr : 00000000000835ec (reloc)
elr: 0000000000080010 lr : 000000003b3545ec
x0 : 0000000080000000 x1 : 000000003af53a38
x2 : 000000003af53a38 x3 : 0000000000080000
x4 : 000000003eb94000 x5 : 0000000000000000
x6 : 000000003eaf0000 x7 : 000000003af4caf0
x8 : 000000003af4c9b0 x9 : 0000000000000002
x10: 00000000ffffffd0 x11: 000000003af565b8
x12: 0000000000000004 x13: 0000000000000200
x14: 000000000000002e x15: 0000000000000008
x16: 0000000000004110 x17: febdb1fc79d3efd0
x18: 000000003af4cde8 x19: 000000003af53a38
x20: 0000000000000002 x21: 0000000000080000
x22: 000000003af53a30 x23: 000000003b3c5238
x24: 0000000000000002 x25: 0000000000000000
x26: 0000000000000000 x27: 0000000000000000
x28: 000000003af53a90 x29: 000000003af4caf0

Resetting CPU ...

resetting ...
```

From there it goes into a loop, trying to download the kernel, and then resetting. The most interesting part is that it makes it to `Starting application...` twice. That is, u-boot runs once, downloads `kernel8.img`,  prints the `Starting application...` message, immediately restarts, downloads `kernel8.img` again, prints `Starting application...` again, and ***then*** prints the `"Synchronous Abort"` message.

I looked up this error message in the u-boot source code. It's printed in the `do_sync()` function, which is called by the fifth entry (index 4) in the interrupt vector table. Can anyone explain what this means, and why this would fail with u-boot, but not when I run it directly from the SD card?

Comment: `eret` is a return instruction that pops values from stack ... determine what is on the stack ... my guess is that it has something to do with the way that the part of the program is called